# Stata Loop Over Subgroups

Tags: stata, survey

```
use https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/seminars/svy_stata_intro/strsrs, clear
svyset [pweight = api00] * we can pretend api00 equals to the weight variable*
tab sch_wide
svy: tab sch_wide
* attempt 1
svy: tab sch_wide, over(both)
* it gives error
* attempt 2
svy, subpop(both): tab sch_wide
* it works but does not give output for all values of 'both'
* i want this:
svy: tab sch_wide if both == 1
svy: tab sch_wide if both == 2
*without having to specify the if both command.
```

Say you have some data that you want to get weighted proportions on and you want that over subgroups. How can you do it without having to specify the if command? I try two things as shown above but they do not work as intended. One gives error and the other does not produce the desired output. Said in another way, I am wondering if and how is it possible to loop weighted tabulations over groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have another underlying reason for not wanting to use `if`, I suggest the following approach that is flexible to any number of levels of `both`.

```
levelsof both

foreach value in `r(levels)' {
    svy: tab sch_wide if both == `value'
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, i am wondering what does "levelsof both" do?

Comment: It lists the levels or categories of a variable, and stores the results in `r(levels)`